How can I turn on Ubuntu wifi and bluetooth adapter?
My Ubuntu 20.04 had a wifi icon and a Bluetooth icon, but my children played with it and now these icons do not appear on start-up. I can turn them on, and when I turn it on it notifies me that I plugged in an adapter or dongle.

Hi Welcome to Ubuntu. I do not understand your question. Please phrase your question in proper English.

''sudo nmcli radio wifi on'
